# Is it possible to query for running/pending animations on an Android View?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Is it possible to find out if a view has currently running animations or pending animations?

I'm not talking about checking if an animation object is running, or about to run, or has run. I'm asking if it's possible to query for animations queued/running on a view when all you have is a reference to that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `view.getAnimation()`?

according to [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getAnimation()) it returns:

> The animation that is currently playing or scheduled to play for this
>   view.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that. For what it's worth, it returns `null` if no animation is running.

Comment: Also, I only have one animation running that I might want to cancel, but if anyone else has multiple animations running and they want to cancel all of them, I guess you could call `getAnimation()` in a loop and terminate when it returns null (I haven't tested this).